# Is it possible to build a project with a com reference with the dotnet CLI?

Tags: msbuild, com, .net-5, dotnet-cli

When I started my new project (`.net 5.0`), I used to script the build using the dotnet CLI: `dotnet build`

Everything worked well until I recently had to add a COM reference to the project:

[image: COM Reference]

(I am not very used to the way this COM stuff works, so forgive me if I misunderstand something and do not hesitate to provide detailed information in your answers)

This addition causes the build with the dotnet CLI to fail:

> MSB4803: The task “ResolveComReference” is not supported on the .NET Core version of MSBuild. Please use the .NET Framework version of MSBuild.

I don't really understand this error since I am using `.NET 5` (I checked with `dotnet --version`) and not `.NET Core` but I guess it's just a remainder from the previous versions of ".NET".

Since the build from Visual Studio works fine, and according to the error message, I switched my automated scripts to use `MSBuild` and everything works fine again.

**But I was wondering if it was still possible to use the `dotnet CLI`?**

I tried to used the [msbuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-msbuild) argument of the `dotnet CLI`, but with the same result:

> ResolveComReference

Comment: .NET 5 is actually .NET Core 5. .NET 5 supports adding COM objects, but it's not using ResolveComReference. This ResolveComReference should be removed as it's not supported as said. Just add a COM object using Visual Studio and you'll see it will add something like `<COMReference Include="MyCOMObject"> etc.` instead which will compile fine.

Comment: I already added the COMReference to the project. And as I said, I already switched my automated script to use MSBuild. My question is not how to do this. It is: **Is it still possible to use the `dotnet CLI`?** With a hack or something. For example, I tried to use the msbuild argument of the dotnet CLI. But it looks like it is not calling the expected msbuild ...

Comment: Well I guess it does. Even if I don't get the point of the **MSBuild** argument in the `dotnet CLI`...